# Что значит «Два кортежа с одинаковыми типами элементов, но с разными именами, совместимы»?

Tags: c#, .net

Читаю [статью на Хабре про кортежи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/345376/) и так сказать с самого начала кое что не понял, а именно вот эту часть кода:

```
// Constructing the tuple instance
var tpl = (1, 2);

// Using tuples with a dictionary
var d = new Dictionary<(int x, int y), (byte a, short b)>();

// Tuples with different names are compatible
d.Add(tpl, (a: 3, b: 4));
...
```

Комментируя как я понимаю именно это выражение `d.Add(tpl, (a: 3, b: 4))` автор пишет

> Два кортежа с одинаковыми типами элементов, но с разными именами,
>   совместимы: (int a, int b) = (1, 2)

Зачем это было отдельно выделять, это ведь тоже самое, к примеру если я прокомментирую следующий код

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = a + b;
```

так: Две переменные имеют разные имена: **a** и **b**, но тип их значений **1** и **2** одинаков (целое число) и это значит, что они совместимы.

**Я прав или тут что-то другое имелось в виду?**

Comment: Что то в данном примере невидно даже кортежей с разными именами при присвоении, имена совпадают `(a: 3, b: 4)` и `(byte a, short b)`

Comment: `var t1 = new { a = 1, b = 2 }; var t2 = new { c = 1; d =2 }; var t3 = (a: 1, b: 2); var t4 = (c: 1; d: 2);` Анонимные типы с разными именами не совместимы: `t1 = t2` выдаст ошибку. Кортежи с разными именами совместимы: `t3 = t4`.

Comment: @PetSerAl я думал `анонимный тип` это тип у которого `нет имени` и в данном случае `t1` и `t2` это `названия переменных`, которые хранят значения анонимных типов. Мы сейчас об одном и том же говорим, но просто по разному, или?

Comment: @adamshakhabov А Вы где-то видите имена у анонимных типов? Вы можете написать эти имена вместо `var`? Да, `t1` и `t2` в данном случае это имена переменных.

Comment: @PetSerAl так Вы же писали "Анонимные типы с разными `именами` ..."

Comment: Имелись в виду имена элементов, как и в Вашем вопросе, а не имена типов.